# Meaning of single a underscore as a method's name, meaning of self._apply() and meaning of @when decorator in Python?

Tags: python, events, decorator

I am watching this lecture from a python conference and at [this point](https://youtu.be/Ru2T4fu3bGQ?t=3217) he shows a code snippet with a python method defined like:

```
@name.setter
def name(self,value):
    event = WorkItem.NameChanged(aggregate_id=self.id,
                                 entity_id=self.id etc etc)
    self._apply(event)

@_when.register(WorkItem.NameChanged)
def _(event,work_item):
    #some code here
```

I don't understand and I cannot find any information on the `self._apply()` method, also no information on the way he registers the event with the `@_when.register()` decorator and finally how can a method be defined with just an `_` as name how can you reference and call it? what does the single underscore do when used alone in a method's name?

**Note**: I know there are potentially different questions here but I don't understand how this code works and I cant find any information anywhere when searching separately.

Comment: Most of what you want to know is specific to whatever framework or library the video is using, and has nothing to do with the *language* itself. Using `_` as a name usually indicates that the name isn't important. For example, you will never call `_` explicitly; the `def` statement's syntax simply requires *some* name, but the resulting function is just passed to `_when.register(WorkItem.NameChanged)` (or more precisely, the callable object that expression evaluates to).

Comment: 1. `_` is a valid identifier in Python and many other languages including C. One-character names are okay and a leading underscore is okay. 2. `_apply()` is a method of whatever class is being defined here. Look for it elsewhere in the class definition. 3. The `@_when` decorator is defined (maybe by an `import`) earlier in the code. You're not finding documentation because these are not Python things, they are specific to the code you are working with. It seems that your video is not presenting sufficient context. Look for accompanying written materials.